# How do I send html/css form results to an email?

Tags: html, css, forms, href, mailto

I have a client in Kanab, Utah who owns a motel. They want a Contact Form that can be sent to their email when filled out. I don't know how to send the results of the form (First name, last name, email, and message) to their email. Here is the form code:

```html
<form action="mailto:kasenlindquist@gmail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain" name="EmailForm">

    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">

    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">

    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email..">

    <!--<label for="country">Country</label>
    <select id="country" name="country">
        <option value="australia">Australia</option>
        <option value="canada">Canada</option>
        <option value="usa">USA</option>
    </select>-->

    <label for="subject">Write a message</label>
    <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Send us a message.." style="height:200px"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

```css
/* Style inputs with type="text", select elements and textareas */
input[type=text],
        select,
        textarea {
    width: 100%;
            /* Full width */
    padding: 12px;
            /* Some padding */
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
            /* Gray border */
    border-radius: 4px;
            /* Rounded borders */
    box-sizing: border-box;
            /* Make sure that padding and width stays in place */
    margin-top: 6px;
            /* Add a top margin */
    margin-bottom: 16px;
            /* Bottom margin */
    resize: vertical
                /* Allow the user to vertically resize the textarea (not horizontally) */
}

        /* Style the submit button with a specific background color etc */
input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #CFB9A5;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

        /* When moving the mouse over the submit button, add a darker green color */
input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #ae8b6b;
}

        /* Add a background color and some padding around the form */
.container {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

I have been trying:

`<form action="mailto:kasenlindquist@gmail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain" name="EmailForm">`

&

`<input type="submit" value="Submit" href="mailto:kasenlindquist@gmail.com">`

and I was expecting it to send me an email with the results of the form.

If you need any further detail I will try to answer your questions I soon as I can, but please be patient because I am quite busy this weekend.

Comment: you need to write server side code for handling form input and sending email

Comment: form action is incorrect `action="mailto:kasenlindquist@gmail.com"` will never work

Comment: if you dont want to use any server side logic check PostMail: https://postmail.invotes.com/

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Form Submit](https://formsubmit.co/) for this, it is free, you will still need some sort of backend database.

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yg6POD0M30w&t=929s) is very good explaining how to make the connections.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that the owners of this motel are very old and don't know how to operate the web very well, so I want a way to get it into their email. If this is like the only way then I am okay with that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).